# Execute a folder action on a schedule

Tags: automator

I am completely new to Automator. I have a folder action setup to copy my Camera Uploads folder from DropBox to iPhoto. Currently, this only occurs when I open Automator and execute it. Can I set this up to run on a schedule, i.e. when the computer starts up, once a week, etc.

Comment: Shouldn't it run automatically whenever to content of the folder changes?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Lingon](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lingon-3/id450201424?mt=12) (Mac App Store link) to set up a schedule to run the Automator action (or pretty much any other program/command for that matter). It's a GUI interface to the [launchd](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/launchd.8.html) command that allows scheduling by time, or on specific events (I believe system start/wake is one of them).